# Controlling RGB-Matrix via SPI (Python)

Tags: python, matrix, spi

The Raspberry Pi has a Broadcom BCM 2835 chip allowing it to interface with SPI devices on its GPIO pins. I encountered a problem adressing LEDs in a 8x8 Matrix via SPI. 
I want to adress single LEDs on the matrix, but I haven't figured out, which bytes adresses which LED(s).
SPIdev seems to be the right library for this purpose und I stumbled upon this snippet of code:

```
import spidev
import time

spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0, 0)
spi.max_speed_hz = 7629

# Split an integer input into a two byte array to send via SPI
def write_pot(input):
    msb = input >> 8
    lsb = input & 0xFF
    spi.xfer([msb, lsb])

# Repeatedly switch a MCP4151 digital pot off then on
while True:
    write_pot(0x1FF)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    write_pot(0x00)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Does anyone know which values adresses (a) specific LED(s)?

In C/C++ adressing works very well via the wiringpi-library, a useful documentation can be found here:
http://wiki.52pi.com/index.php/RPI-RGB-LED-Matrix_SKU:EP-0075